# Dynamic struct array in c using calloc

Tags: c

I´m trying to create dynamic array of `struct article` with `calloc` i have assigned it to return with an array of 2. When i run the code i can enter how many names as i want and when i use `printf` it seems to be more elements than 2. if i enter 5 names it will print out 5 names. when it should only be space for 2 names in the array?

```
struct article{
char name[20];
float number;
char unit[20];


};

int main(void){
  struct article *cart;
  int i = 0;
  char val[2];
  cart = calloc(2, sizeof(struct article));
  int size = 0;
  do{
   printf("Name: ");
   scanf("%s", cart[i].name);




  printf("press x to exit and print names ");
  scanf("%s", val);
  i++;
 }while(val[0] == 'x');
 size = i;
 for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
   printf("%s\n", cart[i].name);

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is that `val[2]` logic supposed to do?  And could you please translate the message to English so more users have a chance of understanding what the user is asked for?

Comment: i did translate it now, i just have it as an argument to ask if want to repeat it agian or to exit and print

Comment: How can it continue to get names when its limit to 2  at calloc(2, sizeof(struct article)) when it goes for more than 2 names